# Can zynq pl cause kernel crash?

Tags: crash, kernel, xilinx, zynq

Our system uses Xilinx Zynq soc.

Sometimes, issues are looked like a kernel crash occurs in our system. Like a network is downed or serial port is downed or serial data is crashed and so on.

However, we didn't modify kernel code and we are not using driver at all. We are just running only applications.

So we considered a case of pl issue. But anyone doesn't know about pl then we can't prove it.

So, as our thought, can Zynq pl cause a kernel crash?
And is there a solution of proving it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes if the PL tanks the AXI bus the kernel can crash.

What I mean is if you for example have an IP with the following behavior:

- It sends the AWADDR for a burst write
- Then it starts sending the data
- But it the middle of the burst the IP gets a reset
  If the IP does not set the WREADY to 1 while in reset the data cannot be transfered and you have a deadlocked bus.

This is only an example as there are many more ways to tank an AXI bus. Without any information on your design or the software that controls it I cannot help you. Your question is very broad.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Another way that PL can crash the kernel is if it writes to memory used by the kernel for its own data structures. This would be very difficult to find from the PL side.